# Org-mode radio table orgtbl-to-latex :fmt wont accept float

Tags: org-mode, latex, auctex

I'd like to embed `org-mode` tables in my latex files and have org mode take care of formatting floating point numbers.
Based on A.6.2 of the `org-mode` manual (http://orgmode.org/org.pdf) I expected this to work, in particular to produce `1.0 & 2.0 \\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
  #+ORGTBL: SEND table-name orgtbl-to-latex :splice t :fmt (1 "%.3s" 2 "%.2f")
 | 1.000 | 2.000 |
\end{comment}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  % BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL table-name
  % END RECEIVE ORGTBL table-name
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, it doesn't. Instead i get an error: `Format specifier doesn't match argument type`

Any ideas? Is `%s` the only supported format or am I missing somthing? (Why?)

Comment: I can work around it by producing additional formatted colums and skip the original, but that seems messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploiting the possibility for `:fmt` to be a function it can be done as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
  #+ORGTBL: SEND table-name orgtbl-to-latex :splice t :fmt (lambda (str) (format "%.2f" (string-to-number str)))
 | 1.000 | 2.000 |
\end{comment}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  % BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL table-name
  % END RECEIVE ORGTBL table-name
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note: `:fmt` can also be a list with pr. column functions such as `(1 fcn1 2 fcn2 ...)`, where `fcn1` is applied to column 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to calculate additional columns and skip the originals:

```
#+ORGTBL: SEND correlation-detection-outcomes orgtbl-to-latex :splice t :skipcols (1 2)
| 1 |  2 | 
#+TBLFM: $3=$1;%.2f::$4=$2;%.2f
```

note the added `#+TBLFM: $3=$1;%.2f::$4=$2;%.2f`, which that has to be executed (?) by putting the point on it an pressing `C-c C-c` before doing the same on the table.

This do however seem bloaty and unecessarily hackish.